# Editing or Viewing data frame in R Console

Tags: r

I can see the entire data frame in the console. Is there any possible way or any function to view data frame in the R-Console (Editing similar to that of Excel) so that I should be able to edit the data manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### S3 method for class 'data.frame'

You can use:

```
edit(name, factor.mode = c("character", "numeric"),
 edit.row.names = any(row.names(name) != 1:nrow(name)), ...)
```

Example:

```
edit(your_dataframe)
```

You can go through in detail with the help of this link - [Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/edit.data.frame.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can view the dataframe with `View()`:

```
View(df)
```

As @David Arenburg says, you can also open your dataframe in an editable view, but be warned this is slow:

edit(df)

For updates/changes to affect the dataframe use:

```
 df <- edit(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

You really can use `edit()` or `view()`.

But maybe, if you dataset isn't big enough, if you prefer to use Excel, you can use this function below:

```
library(xlsx)

view.excel<-function(inputDF,nrows=5000){
  if (class(inputDF)!="data.frame"){
    stop("ERROR: <inputDF> class is not \"data.frame\"")
  }
  if(nrow(inputDF)>5000 & nrows!=-1){
    inputDF=inputDF[1:nrows,]
  }
  tempPath=tempfile(fileext='.xlsx')
  write.xlsx(inputDF,tempPath)
  system(paste0('open ',tempPath))
  return(invisible(tempPath))
}
```

I've defined this function to help me with some tasks in R...

Basically, you only need to pass a DataFrame to the function as a parameter. The function by default display a maximum of 5000 rows (you can set the parameter `nrows = -1` to view all the rows, but it may be slow).

This function opens your DataFrame in Excel and returns the path where your temporary view was saved. If you wanna save and load your temporary view, after changing something directly with Excel, you can load again your data frame with:

```
# Open a view in excel
tempPath <- view.excel(initialDF, nrows=-1)
# Load the file of the Excel View in the new DataFrame modifiedDF
modifiedDF <- read.xlsx(tempPath)
```

This function may works well in Linux, Windows or Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can view and edit a dataframe using with the `fix()` function:

```
#  Open the mtcars dataframe for editing:
fix(mtcars)
#  Edit and close.   

#  This produces the same result:
mtcars <- edit(mtcars)
#  But it is a longer command to write.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a lot of people are using (and developing in) RStudio and Shiny nowadays, things have become far more convenient for R users.

You should look at the [`rhandsontable` package](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable).

There is also very nice Shiny implementation of `rhandsontable`, from a blog I stumbled upon: https://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/shiny_editTable.html. It's not using the console, but it is anyway super slick:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(A few years later) This may be worth trying if you use RStudio: It seems to support all data types. I did not use it extensively but helped me ocassionally:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/editData/README.html

It shows an editing dialog by default. If your dataframe is big you can browse to  http://127.0.0.1:7212 while the dialog is being shown, to get a resizable editing view.